# how to convert "system.object" {string} to integer

Tags: vb.net, registry

I am trying to read and write values in registry. I get return something like "system.object"{string} from reading function. I need to assign the value to a integer variable.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim return As Boolean

Dim result as Int

return = Int32.TryParse("yorstring", result)
```

where return indicates if function can convert string or not

Comment: Dim result As Int32 would help it compile.

Comment: yeah it worked. thnx for help... i tried doing int32.parse but got error so what's the diff between those 2

Answer (score 0):

yes 
you need to parse it using Int32.TryParse("your string", out result)
the function will tell you where you can convert the string to int or not.